# Defining appropriate number of processes

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, benchmarking

I have a python code treating a lot of apache logs (decompress, parse, crunching numbers, regexping etc). One parent process which takes a list of files (up to few millions), and sends a list of files to parse to workers, using multiprocess pool.

I wonder, if there is any guidelines / benchmarks / advices which can help me to **estimate ideal number of child process ?** Ie. having one process per core is better than launching few hundreds of them?

Currently 3/4 time of script execution is reading files and decompressing them, and in terms of resources, its CPU which is 100% loaded, memory and I/O being ok. So I assume there is a lot which can be done with proper multiprocessing settings. Script will be running on different machines / os, so os-specific hints are welcome, too.

Also, is there any benefit in using threads rather than multiprocess?

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder, if there is any guidelines / benchmarks / advices which can help me to estimate ideal number of child process ?

No.

> having one process per core is better than launching few hundreds of them?

You can never know *in advance*.

There are too many degrees of freedom.

You can only discover it empirically by running experiments until you get the level of performance you desire.

> Also, is there any benefit in using threads rather than multiprocess?

Rarely.

Threads don't help much.  Multiple threads doing I/O will be locked up waiting while the process (as a whole) waits for the O/S to finish the I/O request.

Your operating system does a very, very good job of scheduling processes.  When you have I/O intensive operations, you really want multiple processes.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple cores do not provide better performance if the program is I/O bound. The performance might even become worse if the disk is serving two or more masters.

Answer (score 0):

I'll address the last question first. In CPython, it is next to impossible to make sizeable performance gains by distributing CPU-bound load across threads. This is due to the [Global Interpreter Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock). In that respect [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) is a better bet.

As to estimating the ideal number of workers, here is my advice: run some experiments with your code, your data, your hardware and a varying number of workers, and see what you can glean from that in terms of speedups, bottlenecks etc.

Comment: the GIL limitation applies to cPython only.  Other implementations do not suffer from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if current OSes do this, but it used to be that I/O buffers were allocated per-process, so dividing one process' buffer among multiple threads would lead to buffer thrashing.  You're far better off using multiple processes for I/O-heavy tasks.